# Differentiate a real and counterfeit NFT with the same name and symbol

Tags: erc-721, security

Regarding this "We also remind everyone that any smart contract can use the same name and symbol as your contract.", then how do users identify a real and a counterfeit NFT series? If I interpret it correctly, CryptoPunk is the name and CP(or it's some other name? I'm not sure) is the symbol of that ERC-721 series. Then is checking on the transactional volume and price the only way to differentiate the real and counterfeit CryptoPunks? Since both have the same name, symbols, and jpegs.

Comment: the only safe way to identify any token, NFT or ERC20 is using the contract address. You can't fake it even across different ethereum networks (like Polygon, etc)

Comment: Also, it's good to DYOR. Like finding their communities (mostly Twitter or Discord) and making sure that the community is active.